# Iterating sObject to fetch a field value using sObject.get()

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx, sobject

I'm not able to get the sObject fields value in For loop.

Getting `Loop must iterate over collection: SObject`, Can you help me what I am missing here

```
sObject con = [SELECT Id, firstName, LastName FROM Contact];


for(sObject c : con){
id recid = (id)(c.getSObject('sObject').get('Name')); 
string name = String.valueOf(c.getSObject('sObject').get('firstName')); 
System.debug(recid + name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over a `list<Sobject>` instead of sobject.

```
List<sObject> con = [SELECT Id, firstName, LastName FROM Contact];
```

You can learn how to loop through element from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops.htm

Comment: +1, also the query is non-selective, so it would be better to have some condition with the `WHERE` clause.